# Writing on MapPoint status bar

Tags: com, add-in, statusbar, mappoint

I'm creating a MapPoint add-in with Visual Studio 2010. I would like it to write some log messages on MapPoint status bar, to make the user know what it is doing. Is it possible? In the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674771.aspx) status bar it's not even mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is pretty complete. The reason it is not covered, is because the status bar is not exposed by the API.

The only way to do it, is to try and trap Windows messages, and directly manipulate the Status Bar control. This is definitely frowned upon from a security perspective, and "prohibited" by Vista and Win7. It is also undocumented, and could easily be broken by new releases of MapPoint.

Toolbar accessibility is similar, and an often requested feature. You can switch toolbars on/off, but you cannot add your own buttons.